# XEP-0077 In-band registration with Strophe.js and openfire usage

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I'm trying to register a new user on openfire server with the strophe plugin but it doesn't connect for the registration. The description here https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/register doesn't bring me any further :( Do I have to establish a connection before? This is what I try when clicking a button to register:

```
$("#RegButton").click(function () {
var callback = function (status) {
if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTER) {
    connection.register.fields.username = "juliet";
    connection.register.fields.password = "R0m30";
    connection.register.submit();
} else if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTERED) {
    console.log("registered!");
    connection.authenticate();
} else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
    console.log("logged in!");
} else {
    // every other status a connection.connect would receive
}
};
connection.register.connect("http://localhost:7070/http-bind/", callback);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line:

```
connection.register.connect("http://localhost:7070/http-bind/", callback);
```

`connection` should be a [Strophe.Connection](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.0.2/files2/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.Strophe.Connection) object already created with your service URL (`"http://localhost:7070/http-bind/"`).

The first parameter to `connection.register.connect()` is the host that you want to register an account on. That is, for a JID of *user@example.com* you would set it to `"example.com"`, not `"http://localhost:7070/http-bind/"` as in your code.

Answer (score 4):

in my case I modified the plugin, because in line 215 
"if(register.length === 0)", always end my intent for register, so I commented these lines  and removed a tag "x"  than brings in my stanza and the register was posible.
I hope this help you.

```
    /*
      if (register.length === 0) {
        console.log('En tra if de linea 220');
        //that._changeConnectStatus(Strophe.Status.REGIFAIL, null);
        //return;
    } else */
    this.enabled = true;
```

Comment: I've also had the same issues with strophe.register.js and got around by commenting out the same lines. I'm using prosody as XMPP server. What server are you using?