# XMPP - Strophe.register.js

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I am trying to add new user to my XMPP server. I am using strophe.register.js and here is my code

```
var callback = function (status) {
  if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTER) {

        connection.register.fields.username = "juliet";
        connection.register.fields.password = "R0m30";

        connection.register.submit();
      } 
      else if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTERED) {
        console.log("registered!");
        // calling login will authenticate the registered JID.
        connection.register.authenticate();
      } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONFLICT) {
        console.log("Contact already existed!");
      } else if (status === Strophe.Status.NOTACCEPTABLE) {
        console.log("Registration form not properly filled out.")
      } else if (status === Strophe.Status.REGIFAIL) {
        console.log("The Server does not support In-Band Registration")
      } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
        console.log('logged in')
      } else {
        console.log("every other status a connection.connect would receive");
      }
    };


    $("#registerBtn").click(function(){
      connection.register.connect("192.168.1.77/bosh/", callback, 60, 1);

    })
```

when I click the #registerBtn i expect to have user created with uname: juliet and pass: R0m30.

Instead of that i get this error in console:
TypeError: that._buildBody is not a function coming from strophe.register.js line 106

I have checked almost every xmpp-strophe connected question here and I could not find solution.

I tried this solution: [Register XMPP-Account using the Strophe.js-Register-Pluging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550114/register-xmpp-account-using-the-strophe-js-register-pluging) but it did not work for me.
Anyone any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issues too. I got it fixed using this: https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/register.
In addition, make sure "192.168.1.77/bosh/" in connection.register.connect("192.168.1.77/bosh/", callback, 60, 1); is replaced by the name of the host you registered with your XMPP server like ejabberd. An example would be 'example.com' or 'localhost' etcetera.